# protractor - how to select element from multiselect dropdown

Tags: angular, protractor

I am using multiselect dropdown from angular https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown
and want to select element from the dropdown using protractor. DOM element looks like below.
I need to check the checkbox for which value is 'Navkit'.

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown name="dropdown">
    <div class="multiselect-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <ul class="item2">
                <li class="multiselect-item-checkbox">
                    <input _ngcontent-c3="" aria-label="multiselect-item" type="checkbox">
                    <div _ngcontent-c3="">Navkit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Protractor filters to select items form Drop down menu :

```
 this.DDmenueItems = element.all(by.css(".multiselect-item-checkbox"));

//Before selecting value from dropdown make sure to click on Drop down and populate drop down list.


 this.FilterDDSelectField("Navkit");

    exports.FilterDDSelectField = function (fieldname) {
    this.DDmenueItems.filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
          return text.toUpperCase() === fieldname.toUpperCase();
        });
      }).then(function (filteredElements) {
        filteredElements[0].click();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to select the option, the wait I used here is optional which is not necessary

```
await element(by.xpath("//ng-multiselect-dropdown[@name='dropdown']")).click().then(async function () {
                    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                    var yourElement = await element(by.css('li[class="multiselect-item-checkbox"]'));
                    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(yourElement), 25000);
                    await element.all(by.css('li[class="multiselect-item-checkbox"]')).filter(function (elem, index) {
                        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
                            return text === Navkit;
                        });
                    }).first().click();
                });
```